# xampp fail to start, apache running, but apache is not installed!

Tags: apache-httpd, xampp

I am having a strange problem. When I try to start xampp it fails with message:

```
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
```

When I tried to find out which server is running using following command:

```
netstat -tunap | grep LISTEN
```

result:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53        0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN  1955/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631       0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN  1262/cupsd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500       0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN  2353/dropbox       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20414       0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN  2297/skype          
tcp6       0      0 :::80                    :::*        LISTEN  1366/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                  :::*        LISTEN  1262/cupsd
```

Here I see apache is running with, to verify it is installed or not I excuted following command:

```
dpkg -s apache2
```

Result:

```
dpkg-query: package 'apache2' is not installed and no information is available
```

Every Time I have to kill apache2 before starting xampp, which is very irritating. I am on Ubuntu 12.04,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache2 is a metapackage, you need a specific 'worker' of apache2 (mpm is installed on mine) which then provides the apach2 dependancy if necessary.

```
dpkg -l|grep apache
```

Will probably find you what you're trying to find.

You could always just stop it starting up rather than removing it entirely.

Comment: can u please tell more about mpm and how to stop it starting up.

Comment: mpm's just a "style" of worker for apache (how it handles multiple connections), if you want to remove the package, just remove whatever was in the dpkg command above (aptitude remove apache2-mpm for example).  You can just turn it off probably by doing 'update-rc.d apache2 disable 2345'.

Comment: @iain Heh, didn't know that...